# Remove pixels 255 255 255 in GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I want to remove all pixels 255 255 255 from my image, using GDAL, how can I do that?

I used the following command but the result is not as expected,
the picture below depicts what I'm having trouble with, the white streaks are the value pixels (255 255 255)

[image: white stripes are pixels 255 255 255 is the boundary of the insets]

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata 255 reproj_124f_ortho_resize_NODATA.tif reproj_124f_ortho_resize_NODATA_255.tif
```

Comment: what do you mean by "remove"? there must be a pixel there so what will you replace it with?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Assigning nodata into 255 makes those pixels transparent. Place some other layer beneath the aerial image. If you see that background layer through the white line then you have managed to set the nodata correctly. If you have other expectations that's another problem.

Comment: hi Lan Turton, i just want to clip or remove or delete this white line

Comment: @HồngNguyễnVăn `-a_nodata` doesn't remove pixels or clip an image. It only "tells" the rendering software (e.g. QGIS) not to display a specific value. "Removing" pixels or "clipping" an image is something completely different.

Comment: thanks, and i understood what i want, i want to turn 0 and 255 value pixels into nodata

Comment: GeoTIFF supports only one nodata value so 0 and 255 is not possible. But you can set 0 as nodata and update 255 pixels into 0 with a raster calculator.

Comment: thanks all alot! gdal_calc very useful